# Schengen visa Sweden, applied short term visiting family or friend. Can I still do remote work during weekdays?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, india, sweden

To give an overall idea.
I am planning to meet my friend who's residing in Sweden (non-EU).
He has all sort of documents like work permit, accommodation agreement and all.

My whole itinerary will be around 30 days. I am planning to do remote work (my company, based out of India, allows work from anywhere).

Now my question is: can I do remote work during weekdays and tour the country during weekends?

If yes, shall I mention the same in my visa cover letter and cite the same in my itinerary list as a proof that I am not willing to stay more than the intended days. And will positively be back before my visa expires. Or will it affect my visa application?
Do I need to apply for some sort of temporary work permit?

Comment: This is one of those grey areas, but it does weaken your application: if you can work while you are there, what compels you to return home?

Comment: @jcaron What compels you to return home. Pardon didn't understand this question.
My family/friends/job is there why won't I return home. Moreover I love my country it's just that my friend kept calling me to visit them. I do love travel but if I need to go through a lot of paperwork then I might simply give up. Moreover, I am salaried person for last 5.5+ years and the current company which I am working in, is an early stage startup where I love to work and I see a lot of potential there. We might become unicorn in next 2-3 years. Having such an amazing life why would I not return.

Comment: @jcaron This is my first time applying for visa for any country. Sorry if I didn't understand your question. and also I am passionate about my life right now in India. if my above comment sounds rude. Pardon me.

Comment: You have to convince the officer examining your application that you will indeed leave the Schengen Area at the end of your planned stay. The usual reasons are having a job to return to, property, or family (as in spouse and children). If your job does not require you to go back since you are telling them you can work from anywhere, you have one less element trying to prove you’ll go back. Either you are coming for holidays in Sweden (and can show you can afford it), or it’s going to be quite more complex. Note that if you say you are coming for holidays it must be true.

Comment: You should not mention about remote working in the cover letter at all. Once you get the visa then who is stopping you from working on your laptop?

Comment: @jcaron ohh Now I got your point. Anyways, I have already started my visa process and submitted all my documents. Let's see what happens now and yes I am here only for holidays.

Comment: @Aak Yeah that is also true. But still won't try to do anything which might hamper my stay. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Update - I got my visa rejection stating - **there are reasonable doubts as to your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the Visa.** 
@jcaron Man, you were on point. I didn't even realize that thing is a bigger issue in visa application. Did a rookie mistake. Didn't research much. will do a full analysis of what went wrong and update the same so that others can benefit from my experience.

Comment: Update 2 - Got my visa approved last week after applying for the second time.
Things that would have made a difference I guess here is mostly 2 things - 
1. Got NOC from my current employer.
2. Wrote a cover letter stating my purpose of visit.
Moreover, they reached out to my employer for employment verification and also duration of leave granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to work.

From https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Visiting-Sweden/Visit-Sweden-for-less-than-90-days---apply-for-a-visa.html

> a visa is valid for a visit and it is only in exceptional cases that you can work while you have a visa

Work permits are for work that needs to be carried out in Sweden so that is not a way forward for you.